# Failing to use custom base_controller to simulate diff_wheeled robot in gazebo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been reading the book effective robotics programming with ROS and in chapter 5 i'm suppose to run the example of using a custom base controller

*This code is only a common example and must be extended with more code to make
it work with a specific robot. It depends on the controller used, the encoders, and
so on. We assume that you have the right background to add the necessary code
in order to make the example work fine. In Chapter 8, Using Sensors and Actuators
with ROS a fully functional example will be provided with a real robot platform
with wheels and encoders.*

Thats the text from the book. I really do not know why the base_controller is not publishing odometry information
Below is the code

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/JointState.h>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <nav_msgs/Odometry.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double width_robot = 0.1;
double vl = 0.0;
double vr = 0.0;
ros::Time last_time;    
double right_enc = 0.0;
double left_enc = 0.0;
double right_enc_old = 0.0;
double left_enc_old = 0.0;
double distance_left = 0.0;
double distance_right = 0.0;
double ticks_per_meter = 100;
double x = 0.0;
double y = 0.0;
double th = 0.0;
geometry_msgs::Quaternion odom_quat;

void cmd_velCallback(const geometry_msgs::Twist &twist_aux)
{
    geometry_msgs::Twist twist = twist_aux; 
    double vel_x = twist_aux.linear.x;
    double vel_th = twist_aux.angular.z;
    double right_vel = 0.0;
    double left_vel = 0.0;

    if(vel_x == 0){  // turning
        right_vel = vel_th * width_robot / 2.0;
        left_vel = (-1) * right_vel;
    }else if(vel_th == 0){ // fordward / backward
        left_vel = right_vel = vel_x;
    }else{ // moving doing arcs
        left_vel = vel_x - vel_th * width_robot / 2.0;
        right_vel = vel_x + vel_th * width_robot / 2.0;
    }
    vl = left_vel;
    vr = right_vel; 
}


int main(int argc, char** argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "base_controller");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Subscriber cmd_vel_sub = n.subscribe("cmd_vel", 10, cmd_velCallback);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

    while(ros::ok())
    {

        double dxy = 0.0;
        double dth = 0.0;
        ros::Time current_time = ros::Time::now();
        double dt;
        double velxy = dxy / dt;
        double velth = dth / dt;

        ros::spinOnce();
        dt =  (current_time - last_time).toSec();;
        last_time = current_time;

        // calculate odomety
        if(right_enc == 0.0){
            distance_left = 0.0;
            distance_right = 0.0;
        }else{
            distance_left = (left_enc - left_enc_old) / ticks_per_meter;
            distance_right = (right_enc - right_enc_old) / ticks_per_meter;
        } 

        left_enc_old = left_enc;
        right_enc_old = right_enc;

        dxy = (distance_left + distance_right) / 2.0;
        dth = (distance_right - distance_left) / width_robot;

        if(dxy != 0){
            x += dxy * cosf(dth);
            y += dxy * sinf(dth);
        }   

        if(dth != 0){
            th += dth;
        }
        odom_quat = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromRollPitchYaw(0,0,th);
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273311/failing-to-use-custom-base_controller-to-simulate-diff_wheeled-robot-in-gazebo/) by [darula-hpp](https://answers.ros.org/users/32289/darula-hpp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The code that you attached is incomplete. Nowhere in the code the *right_enc* and *left_enc* are updated and there is no reference to any odometry publisher.

I think the book is leaving it as an exercise for the reader.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2017-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [darula-hpp](https://answers.ros.org/users/32289/darula-hpp/) on 2017-10-18**:
@Martin Peris thanks, i think the problem is that their is no reference to the odometry. I will try to figure out how to add the odometry reference and you may also help me if you have an idea.